# Angular rxjs : The List Object map method is not consistency?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I don't know why my code is returning unexpected output, I assume I am not familiar with the logic how to use map method. The map return confirms and schedules separately. I would like to get the result as below, but it output empty list twice. sometime the first one is empty, the example below I gave is the other result. Any help will be much appreciated!

This is a typescript code using rxjs map if i understand right.

Code here:

```
const confirms = this.List.map(r => {
          console.log('confirmed',r.map(c => c.ConfirmedCapacity));
          return r.map(c => c.ConfirmedCapacity)[etaIndex];
        });

const schedules = this.List.map(r => {
          console.log('scheduled',r.map(c => c.ConfirmedCapacity));
              return r.map(c => c.ScheduledCapacity)[etaIndex];
        });
```

Expected result:

```
confirmed (21) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
scheduled (21) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Get :

```
confirmed (21) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
confirmed (21) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
scheduled (21) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
scheduled (21) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: How is this rxjs code ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Is map() from rxjs?

Comment: Not the one used here.

Comment: Looks like you're using the `.map` array function?

Comment: `this.List` appears to be an array containing two other arrays. You have two outputs for each `map` call - one for each inner array. Please add more details to explain what you're trying to do.